# Динамический tree Store Ext js

Tags: java, extjs, facade

Пытаюсь реализовать Динамический `tree Store` на `Ext js` в фасаде формирую `json` и передаю его указав parentId. Но я не могу заставить его стать `childom`

мой `tree`

```
treeFactory : function(treeName, lStore, lColumns) {
        Ext.define(treeName, {
            extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
            alias : 'widget.dictree1',
            border : false,
            store : lStore,
            collapsible : false,
            useArrows: false,
            rootVisible: false,
            rootText: 'Справочники',
            rootId: 'root',
            columns : lColumns,
            autoScroll : true
        });
        return Ext.create(treeName);
    },
```

мой store

```
storeFactory : function(storeName, lModel) {
        Ext.define(storeName, {
            extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
            model : lModel,
            parentIdProperty: 'parentId',
            autoLoad : false,
            root: {
                text: 'Справочники',
                expanded: true,
                id: 'root'
            },
            proxy : {
                type : 'rest',
                noCache : true,
                url : 'services/ClsTreeResource',
                reader : 'json',
                headers : {
                    Accept : 'application/json'
                }
            }
        });
        return Ext.create(storeName);
    },
```

мой `model`

```
modelFactory : function(modelName, lFields) {
        return Ext.define(modelName, {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty : 'id',
            fields : lFields,
            hasMany : [ {
                name : 'childern',
                model : modelName,
                associationKey : 'childern'
            } ]
        });
    },
```

часть кода на фасаде `id` 20 это родитель а `id` 40 это должен быть его `childom`

```
clsDTO = new ClsDTO();
                clsDTO.setId(20);
                clsDTO.setParentId(0);
                clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("monitoring.menumode.enum." + lang));
                answ.add(clsDTO);

                clsDTO = new ClsDTO();
                clsDTO.setId(40);
                clsDTO.setParentId(20);
                clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("byindate.menumode.enum." + lang));
                clsDTO.setLeaf(properties.getProperty("byindate.menumode.enum.leaf"));
                answ.add(clsDTO);
```

Результат такой ни как не получилось сделать `child` для парента, как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно передавать дочерние элементы указав `parentId`. Поле `parentId` нужен для того:
когда кликаешь по родителю он отправляет на сервер переменную node с `ID` родителя. 
на сервере делаешь выборку у кого `parentId = node` и возвращаешь `json`.